# Time complexity of convex hull algorithm

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

The complexity of the convex hull algorithm can be represented in summation notation as:

```
1 C(n)=sum(i=1..n-1)sum(j=i+1..n)sum(k=1..n)1
2 =sum(i=1..n-1)sum(j=i+1..n)n
3 =nsum(i=1..n-1)sum(j=i+1..n)1
4 =nsum(i=1..n-1)(n-i)
```

And from here my professor jumped straight to:

```
5 =nsum(i=1..n-1)i
6 =n*n(n-1)/2
7 =(n^3-n^2)/2
```

I don't get how he just got rid of the n on line 4.
I tried a different approach and got a totally different answer:

```
5 =nsum(i=1..n-1)n - sum(i=1..n-1)i
6 =nsum(i=1..n-1)n - n(n-1)/2
7 =n^2sum(i=1..n-1)1 - n(n-1)/2
8 =n^2(n-1) - n(n-1)/2
9 =n^3-n^2 - n^2/2 - n/2
```

Can anyone explain how my professor got rid of the n and why my solution is incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with summation notation, but if (4) represents "the sum of (n-i) for i=1 to n-1", then that is the same as "the sum of (i) for i=1 to n-1". it's the difference between 5+4+3+2+1 and 1+2+3+4+5.

Comment: Thanks @Blorgbeard

Answer (score 1):

To see where the error is, all you need to do is choose a small number for `n` and see how the math works out. So let's choose `n=3`.

```
4 =3sum(i=1..2)(3-i) = 3(2+1) = 9
5 =3sum(i=1..2)i     = 3(1+2) = 9
```

Now yours

```
5 =3sum(i=1..2)3 - sum(i=1..2)i = 3(3+3) - (1+2) = 18-3 = 15
```

The problem is that you didn't multiply both terms by `n`

```
5 =n(sum(i=1..n-1)n - sum(i=1..n-1)i)
6 =n( (n-1)n - (n-1)n/2 ) 
7 =n( (n-1)n/2 )
```

Comment: Thanks! But why does (n-1)n disappear from lines 6-7?

Comment: @JohnT To go from line 6 to 7, think of `x - x/2`

Answer (score 0):

Expand the terms:

```
nsum(i=1..n-1)(n-i) = (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n-(n-1))=1
```

Now look at them in reverse:

```
1 + ... (n-2) + (n-1) = sum(i=1..n-1)i
```